# GIS Cloud Publisher for ArcMap extension does not work

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, cloud-gis

GIS Cloud Publisher is an extension from GISCLOUD.COM that allows one to publish from ArcMap to GIS cloud directly. I followed the instruction provided on the website concerning the installation but it does not work. I does not appear in the Toolbars in Arcmap.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3

Can anyone help with how to make the the GIS Cloud Publisher extension appear or work in ARCMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Solution is Simple**

1. ArcMap > Customize (Menu Bar) > Extension
2. Check(Tick) GIS Cloud Publisher
3. Right Click the Toolbar and Enable GIS Cloud Toolbar.

The problem has to do with the license permission.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a late response. 
I guess you have read the [tutorial](http://www.giscloud.com/manual/publisher-for-arcmap/tutorial-publisher-for-arcmap/).

There could be a problem if you don't have NET 4.5 installed on your computer.

> "Note: If you don’t have 4.5.NET installed on your computer, install
>   it before installing Publisher for ArcMap extension. Also make sure
>   that firewall is not blocking the app."

Please, let me know if this worked out.